# Hecke regularization of weight-2 Eisenstein series and differentiating under the infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

I have a "proof" of the false fact that the Hecke regularized Eisenstein series
$$ E_2(\tau) = \lim_{s\to 0} \sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m+\tau n)^2 |m+\tau n|^s}$$
is holomorphic; could someone help me figure out where I'm being too naive?

If we write
$$ E_2(\tau, s) = \sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m+\tau n)^2 |m+\tau n|^s},$$
it converges absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of the upper half-plane for $\text{Re }s>0$. Thus, for $\text{Re }s>0$,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\tau}}E_2(\tau, s) = \sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\tau}}\frac{1}{(m+\tau n)^2 |m+\tau n|^s} $$
and the RHS is still an absolutely convergent sum which approaches $0$ as $s\to 0$ since we pick up a factor of $s$ from the antiholomorphic derivative. Thus, by continuity, $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\tau}}E_2(\tau, 0)=0$, i.e. it's holomorphic.

Comment: it's what you said.